# Diseño JTable en Java

Tags: java, jtable

estoy realizando un proyecto para la uni de control de notas y estoy trabajando con la interfaz de swing, mi duda es como puedo realizar esto a un jtable o alguna sugerencia. Más que todo en la parte de "Lapsos" para poder juntar las columnas de esa manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Héctor Rodríguez, se me ocurre que el enfoque más sencillo, es crear la cabecera con JLabel's, y las filas en un JTable, si no necesitas barras verticales, no "metes" la tabla en un JScrollPane, de esta forma, no se genera la cabecera, si las necesitas, lo metes dentro, y te fijas en el orden en que pones **panel.add( tabla); panel.add(label);**, etc, de esta forma determinas cual se dibuja arriba y cual abajo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu sugerencia, se me ha ocurrido una idea y es agregar la imagen en la Table Header, simplificando el proceso

Comment: Quedando tal que así https://prnt.sc/JypQrW6w3y3f

Comment: solo puedo decir magnífico!!!